# How to set the explorer font to monospace in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In WebStorm, the font used in the Project tool window is monospaced, but I couldn't find the related settings in VS Code to change it to monospaced.

Setting "editor.fontFamily" does not take effect on the font used in the Explorer panel.

Webstorm:

[image: webstorm]

VS Code:

[image: vscode]